How can I parse this raw radar file (extension .cdr) given to me from the FAA?
I recently received some radar data from the FAA. Both files were formatted with the .cdr file extension, however these are not CorelDraw files. They seem to be binary files with some ASCII text metadata.
Both files correspond to the same date/time location as requested. It's about 3 hours of data. One is from the SBA, the other is from SCT. Both of these are TRACON sites.
I've done a hex dump of the first 400 lines of the data below. I don't see any open source programs that immediately know how to handle this data, does anyone know how I might be able to parse the data into a viewable format?
hexdump -C SBA-17JUL24_0200-0500Z.cdr | head -n 400
00000000  53 49 54 45 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |SITE            |
00000010  20 20 41 41 41 0a 53 54  41 52 54 20 44 41 54 45  |  AAA.START DATE|
00000020  20 41 4e 44 20 54 49 4d  45 20 49 4e 20 42 4f 54  | AND TIME IN BOT|
00000030  48 20 47 4d 54 20 41 4e  44 20 53 59 53 54 45 4d  |H GMT AND SYSTEM|
00000040  20 54 49 4d 45 3a 0a 20  20 20 20 20 20 53 59 53  | TIME:.      SYS|
00000050  54 45 4d 20 54 49 4d 45  3a 31 37 2d 4a 55 4c 2d  |TEM TIME:17-JUL-|
00000060  32 30 32 34 20 30 31 3a  35 37 3a 30 30 2e 30 30  |2024 01:57:00.00|
00000070  32 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20  47 4d 54 20 54 49 4d 45  |2.      GMT TIME|
00000080  3a 20 20 20 31 37 2d 4a  55 4c 2d 32 30 32 34 20  |:   17-JUL-2024 |
00000090  47 30 31 3a 35 37 3a 30  30 2e 30 30 32 0a 53 59  |G01:57:00.002.SY|
000000a0  53 54 45 4d 20 49 4e 46  4f 3a 0a 20 20 20 20 20  |STEM INFO:.     |
000000b0  20 53 59 53 54 45 4d 20  49 44 3a 53 59 53 31 20  | SYSTEM ID:SYS1 |
000000c0  0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 53  45 52 56 49 43 45 20 4c  |.      SERVICE L|
000000d0  45 56 45 4c 3a 46 53 20  0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 4d  |EVEL:FS .      M|
000000e0  4f 44 45 3a 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 4e 6f 72 6d 61  |ODE:       Norma|
000000f0  6c 0a 53 4f 46 54 57 41  52 45 3a 20 20 20 20 20  |l.SOFTWARE:     |
00000100  20 20 20 20 73 36 2e 30  30 72 31 30 61 2e 30 33  |    s6.00r10a.03|
00000110  5f 30 31 31 31 32 34 5f  66 73 5f 73 77 5f 62 75  |_011124_fs_sw_bu|
00000120  69 6c 64 2e 62 6c 5f 61  32 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 20  |ild.bl_a2,.     |
00000130  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 73 36 2e  |             s6.|
00000140  30 30 72 31 30 61 2e 30  33 5f 30 31 31 31 32 34  |00r10a.03_011124|
00000150  5f 66 73 5f 73 65 6e 73  69 73 5f 73 77 5f 62 75  |_fs_sensis_sw_bu|
00000160  69 6c 64 2e 62 6c 5f 61  32 0a 41 44 41 50 54 41  |ild.bl_a2.ADAPTA|
00000170  54 49 4f 4e 3a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 73 62 61 5f  |TION:       sba_|
00000180  72 31 30 61 64 33 5f 79  37 5f 31 30 61 5f 61 64  |r10ad3_y7_10a_ad|
00000190  5f 59 37 31 30 41 2e 62  6c 5f 65 33 0a 43 48 45  |_Y710A.bl_e3.CHE|
000001a0  43 4b 53 55 4d 20 42 4b  57 44 3a 32 33 37 33 37  |CKSUM BKWD:23737|
000001b0  38 35 36 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 0a 50 41 52 54 49  |856       .PARTI|
000001c0  54 49 4f 4e 3a 46 53 4c  41 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TION:FSLA.......|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000fa000  6c 69 62 6e 6f 73 5f 6c  69 62 2e 73 6f 00 00 00  |libnos_lib.so...|
000fa010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000fa060  00 00 00 00 30 30 30 30  37 37 35 00 30 30 32 33  |....0000775.0023|
000fa070  36 34 32 00 30 30 30 32  31 37 36 00 30 30 30 30  |642.0002176.0000|
000fa080  32 34 32 36 30 35 34 00  31 34 35 34 37 36 32 37  |2426054.14547627|
000fa090  36 34 37 00 30 30 31 34  33 32 30 00 30 00 00 00  |647.0014320.0...|
000fa0a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000fa100  00 75 73 74 61 72 00 30  30 63 68 6f 61 6e 67 00  |.ustar.00choang.|
000fa110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 73 74 61 72 73 00 00  |.........stars..|
000fa130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 30 30 30 30 34 37 36  |.........0000476|
000fa150  00 30 30 30 30 30 34 32  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.0000042........|
000fa160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000fa200  7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 06  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
000fa210  03 00 03 00 01 00 00 00  c8 10 02 00 34 00 00 00  |............4...|
000fa220  1c 28 0a 00 00 00 00 00  34 00 20 00 04 00 28 00  |.(......4. ...(.|
000fa230  1a 00 19 00 fd ff ff 6f  b4 00 00 00 b4 00 00 00  |.......o........|
000fa240  00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
000fa250  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa260  00 00 00 00 17 37 03 00  17 37 03 00 05 00 00 00  |.....7...7......|
000fa270  00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  18 37 03 00 18 37 04 00  |.........7...7..|
000fa280  00 00 00 00 c0 66 00 00  30 e1 02 00 07 00 00 00  |.....f..0.......|
000fa290  00 00 01 00 02 00 00 00  c4 00 00 00 c4 00 00 00  |................|
000fa2a0  00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  |................|
000fa2b0  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa2c0  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  34 28 00 00 0c 00 00 00  |........4(......|
000fa2d0  30 2c 03 00 0d 00 00 00  4c 2c 03 00 04 00 00 00  |0,......L,......|
000fa2e0  c4 01 00 00 05 00 00 00  a8 40 00 00 0a 00 00 00  |.........@......|
000fa2f0  82 2a 00 00 06 00 00 00  c8 16 00 00 0b 00 00 00  |.*..............|
000fa300  10 00 00 00 f8 fd ff 6f  a3 ba 00 00 fe ff ff 6f  |.......o.......o|
000fa310  2c 6b 00 00 ff ff ff 6f  01 00 00 00 fa ff ff 6f  |,k.....o.......o|
000fa320  21 03 00 00 16 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00  |!...............|
000fa330  d8 70 00 00 12 00 00 00  28 b3 00 00 13 00 00 00  |.p......(.......|
000fa340  08 00 00 00 10 00 00 60  b4 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00  |.......`........|
000fa350  04 00 00 00 fb ff ff 6f  00 00 00 00 19 00 00 60  |.......o.......`|
000fa360  00 02 00 00 1b 00 00 60  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.......`........|
000fa370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000fa3c0  00 00 00 00 a1 02 00 00  9e 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa3d0  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |................|
000fa3e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  |................|
000fa3f0  00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00  0a 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00  |................|
000fa400  0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  11 00 00 00 13 00 00 00  |................|
000fa410  16 00 00 00 18 00 00 00  19 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00  |................|
000fa420  1c 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00  |................|
000fa430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00  |................|
000fa440  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........ .......|
000fa450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 00 00 00 23 00 00 00  |........!...#...|
000fa460  24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  29 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |$.......).......|
000fa470  2b 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00  2d 00 00 00 2f 00 00 00  |+...,...-.../...|
000fa480  32 00 00 00 34 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |2...4...........|
000fa490  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  35 00 00 00 36 00 00 00  |........5...6...|
000fa4a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  37 00 00 00 39 00 00 00  |........7...9...|
000fa4b0  3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |<...............|
000fa4c0  3d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3f 00 00 00 41 00 00 00  |=.......?...A...|
000fa4d0  00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00  43 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....B...C.......|
000fa4e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  47 00 00 00 49 00 00 00  |........G...I...|
000fa4f0  4c 00 00 00 4e 00 00 00  50 00 00 00 52 00 00 00  |L...N...P...R...|
000fa500  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  53 00 00 00 55 00 00 00  |........S...U...|
000fa510  00 00 00 00 56 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 57 00 00 00  |....V.......W...|
000fa520  59 00 00 00 5b 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 5c 00 00 00  |Y...[.......\...|
000fa530  00 00 00 00 5d 00 00 00  5f 00 00 00 60 00 00 00  |....]..._...`...|
000fa540  00 00 00 00 61 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....a...........|
000fa550  00 00 00 00 62 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....b...........|
000fa560  65 00 00 00 67 00 00 00  69 00 00 00 6a 00 00 00  |e...g...i...j...|
000fa570  6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  6d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |k.......m.......|
000fa580  6e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n.......o.......|
000fa590  00 00 00 00 70 00 00 00  72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....p...r.......|
000fa5a0  74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  76 00 00 00 79 00 00 00  |t.......v...y...|
000fa5b0  7b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |{...............|
000fa5c0  7c 00 00 00 7f 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  ||...............|
000fa5d0  81 00 00 00 82 00 00 00  83 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa5e0  84 00 00 00 85 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 87 00 00 00  |................|
000fa5f0  8a 00 00 00 8b 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa600  8c 00 00 00 8e 00 00 00  90 00 00 00 92 00 00 00  |................|
000fa610  00 00 00 00 93 00 00 00  95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa620  97 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  98 00 00 00 99 00 00 00  |................|
000fa630  9a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9b 00 00 00 9c 00 00 00  |................|
000fa640  00 00 00 00 9e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 a0 00 00 00  |................|
000fa650  a1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a2 00 00 00 a3 00 00 00  |................|
000fa660  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa670  a6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a8 00 00 00 ab 00 00 00  |................|
000fa680  00 00 00 00 ac 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa690  ae 00 00 00 af 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6a0  b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b2 00 00 00 b3 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6b0  b4 00 00 00 b5 00 00 00  b6 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6c0  ba 00 00 00 bd 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  bf 00 00 00 c0 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6e0  c2 00 00 00 c4 00 00 00  c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa6f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c8 00 00 00 c9 00 00 00  |................|
000fa700  00 00 00 00 ca 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa710  00 00 00 00 cb 00 00 00  cc 00 00 00 ce 00 00 00  |................|
000fa720  cf 00 00 00 d0 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa730  d2 00 00 00 d3 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 d5 00 00 00  |................|
000fa740  d6 00 00 00 d7 00 00 00  d9 00 00 00 da 00 00 00  |................|
000fa750  db 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 dc 00 00 00  |................|
000fa760  de 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00  e1 00 00 00 e2 00 00 00  |................|
000fa770  e3 00 00 00 e4 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 e5 00 00 00  |................|
000fa780  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e6 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00  |................|
000fa790  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  eb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa7a0  00 00 00 00 ed 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa7b0  ee 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f1 00 00 00 f2 00 00 00  |................|
000fa7c0  f4 00 00 00 f7 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 fa 00 00 00  |................|
000fa7d0  fc 00 00 00 fe 00 00 00  00 01 00 00 05 01 00 00  |................|
000fa7e0  06 01 00 00 08 01 00 00  0a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa7f0  0b 01 00 00 0c 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa800  0d 01 00 00 0f 01 00 00  10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa810  11 01 00 00 12 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa820  13 01 00 00 14 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa830  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  15 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa840  17 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 18 01 00 00  |................|
000fa850  1b 01 00 00 1d 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 1e 01 00 00  |................|
000fa860  1f 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 01 00 00 23 01 00 00  |........!...#...|
000fa870  25 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 27 01 00 00  |%...........'...|
000fa880  28 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  2a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(.......*.......|
000fa890  00 00 00 00 2c 01 00 00  2d 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....,...-.......|
000fa8a0  2e 01 00 00 2f 01 00 00  32 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..../...2.......|
000fa8b0  33 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  35 01 00 00 36 01 00 00  |3.......5...6...|
000fa8c0  38 01 00 00 3a 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 3b 01 00 00  |8...:.......;...|
000fa8d0  3c 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  3e 01 00 00 41 01 00 00  |<.......>...A...|
000fa8e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  42 01 00 00 44 01 00 00  |........B...D...|
000fa8f0  45 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  46 01 00 00 47 01 00 00  |E.......F...G...|
000fa900  00 00 00 00 49 01 00 00  4a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....I...J.......|
000fa910  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  4c 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........L.......|
000fa920  00 00 00 00 4e 01 00 00  51 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....N...Q.......|
000fa930  52 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  53 01 00 00 54 01 00 00  |R.......S...T...|
000fa940  56 01 00 00 58 01 00 00  5a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |V...X...Z.......|
000fa950  00 00 00 00 5b 01 00 00  5d 01 00 00 5e 01 00 00  |....[...]...^...|
000fa960  00 00 00 00 5f 01 00 00  63 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...._...c.......|
000fa970  00 00 00 00 64 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...........|
000fa980  65 01 00 00 66 01 00 00  67 01 00 00 69 01 00 00  |e...f...g...i...|
000fa990  6a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00  |j...........n...|
000fa9a0  70 01 00 00 72 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 73 01 00 00  |p...r.......s...|
000fa9b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fa9c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  74 01 00 00 75 01 00 00  |........t...u...|
000fa9d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  76 01 00 00 7a 01 00 00  |........v...z...|
000fa9e0  7c 01 00 00 7f 01 00 00  80 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ||...............|
000fa9f0  81 01 00 00 82 01 00 00  83 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faa00  84 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  86 01 00 00 88 01 00 00  |................|
000faa10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 89 01 00 00  |................|
000faa20  8b 01 00 00 8c 01 00 00  8f 01 00 00 90 01 00 00  |................|
000faa30  92 01 00 00 95 01 00 00  96 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faa40  00 00 00 00 97 01 00 00  9a 01 00 00 9b 01 00 00  |................|
000faa50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9c 01 00 00 9d 01 00 00  |................|
000faa60  9f 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  a2 01 00 00 a3 01 00 00  |................|
000faa70  a4 01 00 00 a6 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faa80  a7 01 00 00 a8 01 00 00  a9 01 00 00 ab 01 00 00  |................|
000faa90  ad 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ae 01 00 00  |................|
000faaa0  00 00 00 00 af 01 00 00  b1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faab0  b2 01 00 00 b3 01 00 00  b5 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faac0  00 00 00 00 b6 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 b7 01 00 00  |................|
000faad0  00 00 00 00 b9 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faae0  00 00 00 00 ba 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 bb 01 00 00  |................|
000faaf0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fab00  bd 01 00 00 be 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 c0 01 00 00  |................|
000fab10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 c3 01 00 00  |................|
000fab20  c5 01 00 00 c6 01 00 00  c9 01 00 00 ca 01 00 00  |................|
000fab30  cc 01 00 00 ce 01 00 00  cf 01 00 00 d0 01 00 00  |................|
000fab40  00 00 00 00 d2 01 00 00  d3 01 00 00 d4 01 00 00  |................|
000fab50  d5 01 00 00 d7 01 00 00  d8 01 00 00 d9 01 00 00  |................|
000fab60  db 01 00 00 dd 01 00 00  de 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fab70  df 01 00 00 e0 01 00 00  e1 01 00 00 e4 01 00 00  |................|
000fab80  e6 01 00 00 e7 01 00 00  e8 01 00 00 ea 01 00 00  |................|
000fab90  ed 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ee 01 00 00  |................|
000faba0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fabb0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ef 01 00 00  |................|
000fabc0  f1 01 00 00 f2 01 00 00  f3 01 00 00 f4 01 00 00  |................|
000fabd0  f5 01 00 00 f7 01 00 00  f9 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fabe0  fa 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  fb 01 00 00 fc 01 00 00  |................|
000fabf0  fd 01 00 00 fe 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fac00  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00  01 02 00 00 02 02 00 00  |................|
000fac10  04 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 05 02 00 00  |................|
000fac20  06 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  07 02 00 00 08 02 00 00  |................|
000fac30  00 00 00 00 0c 02 00 00  0d 02 00 00 0e 02 00 00  |................|
000fac40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fac50  10 02 00 00 11 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 12 02 00 00  |................|
000fac60  14 02 00 00 15 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 16 02 00 00  |................|
000fac70  18 02 00 00 1b 02 00 00  1d 02 00 00 1e 02 00 00  |................|
000fac80  21 02 00 00 22 02 00 00  26 02 00 00 27 02 00 00  |!..."...&...'...|
000fac90  28 02 00 00 2a 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(...*...........|
000faca0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 2b 02 00 00  |............+...|
000facb0  2c 02 00 00 2e 02 00 00  30 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |,.......0.......|
000facc0  31 02 00 00 32 02 00 00  33 02 00 00 34 02 00 00  |1...2...3...4...|
000facd0  35 02 00 00 36 02 00 00  37 02 00 00 3a 02 00 00  |5...6...7...:...|
000face0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3b 02 00 00 3c 02 00 00  |........;...<...|
000facf0  00 00 00 00 3d 02 00 00  3e 02 00 00 3f 02 00 00  |....=...>...?...|
000fad00  41 02 00 00 42 02 00 00  44 02 00 00 45 02 00 00  |A...B...D...E...|
000fad10  46 02 00 00 47 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 49 02 00 00  |F...G.......I...|
000fad20  4a 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  4c 02 00 00 4f 02 00 00  |J.......L...O...|
000fad30  50 02 00 00 51 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 52 02 00 00  |P...Q.......R...|
000fad40  53 02 00 00 55 02 00 00  56 02 00 00 57 02 00 00  |S...U...V...W...|
000fad50  00 00 00 00 58 02 00 00  59 02 00 00 5c 02 00 00  |....X...Y...\...|
000fad60  5d 02 00 00 62 02 00 00  63 02 00 00 64 02 00 00  |]...b...c...d...|
000fad70  67 02 00 00 6a 02 00 00  6c 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |g...j...l.......|
000fad80  6d 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  6f 02 00 00 71 02 00 00  |m.......o...q...|
000fad90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  72 02 00 00 74 02 00 00  |........r...t...|
000fada0  76 02 00 00 77 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 78 02 00 00  |v...w.......x...|
000fadb0  79 02 00 00 7b 02 00 00  7d 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |y...{...}.......|
000fadc0  7e 02 00 00 7f 02 00 00  80 02 00 00 81 02 00 00  |~...............|
000fadd0  84 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  85 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fade0  89 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  8a 02 00 00 8c 02 00 00  |................|
000fadf0  00 00 00 00 8d 02 00 00  8e 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fae00  90 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 91 02 00 00  |................|
000fae10  94 02 00 00 95 02 00 00  96 02 00 00 97 02 00 00  |................|
000fae20  98 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  99 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fae30  00 00 00 00 9a 02 00 00  9b 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fae40  9c 02 00 00 9d 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fae50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
000fae60  05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  |................|
000fae70  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fae80  00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00  0f 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  |................|
000fae90  00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00  |................|
000faea0  15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faeb0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faec0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000faed0  00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...."...........|
000faee0  25 00 00 00 26 00 00 00  27 00 00 00 28 00 00 00  |%...&...'...(...|
000faef0  00 00 00 00 2a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....*...........|
000faf00  00 00 00 00 2e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00  |............0...|
000faf10  31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |1.......3.......|
000faf20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 38 00 00 00  |............8...|
000faf30  00 00 00 00 3a 00 00 00  3b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....:...;.......|
000faf40  00 00 00 00 3e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  |....>.......@...|
000faf50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 00 00  |............D...|
000faf60  45 00 00 00 46 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00  |E...F.......H...|
000faf70  00 00 00 00 4a 00 00 00  4b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....J...K.......|
000faf80  4d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  4f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |M.......O.......|
000faf90  51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 54 00 00 00  |Q...........T...|
000fafa0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 58 00 00 00  |............X...|
000fafb0  00 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Z...........|
000fafc0  00 00 00 00 5e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....^...........|
000fafd0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  63 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  |........c...d...|
000fafe0  00 00 00 00 66 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00  |....f.......h...|
000faff0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 6c 00 00 00  |............l...|
000fb000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb010  71 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |q.......s.......|
000fb020  75 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 00 00 00 78 00 00 00  |u.......w...x...|
000fb030  00 00 00 00 7a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....z...........|
000fb040  7d 00 00 00 7e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |}...~...........|
000fb050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb060  00 00 00 00 86 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00  |................|
000fb070  89 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb080  8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  8f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb090  91 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 94 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0a0  00 00 00 00 96 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0c0  9d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 a4 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb0f0  a9 00 00 00 aa 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb100  ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb110  b1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb130  b9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  bb 00 00 00 bc 00 00 00  |................|
000fb140  00 00 00 00 be 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb150  c1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb160  00 00 00 00 c6 00 00 00  c7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb180  cd 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb190  d1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 d4 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 d8 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1c0  dd 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  df 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb1f0  e9 00 00 00 ea 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ec 00 00 00  |................|
000fb200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ef 00 00 00 f0 00 00 00  |................|
000fb210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb220  f5 00 00 00 f6 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 f8 00 00 00  |................|
000fb230  f9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  fb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb240  fd 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb250  01 01 00 00 02 01 00 00  03 01 00 00 04 01 00 00  |................|
000fb260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  07 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb270  09 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb280  00 00 00 00 0e 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb290  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb2a0  00 00 00 00 16 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb2b0  19 01 00 00 1a 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 1c 01 00 00  |................|
000fb2c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 20 01 00 00  |............ ...|
000fb2d0  00 00 00 00 22 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 24 01 00 00  |....".......$...|
000fb2e0  00 00 00 00 26 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....&...........|
000fb2f0  29 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  2b 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |).......+.......|
000fb300  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 30 01 00 00  |............0...|
000fb310  31 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 34 01 00 00  |1...........4...|
000fb320  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  37 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........7.......|
000fb330  39 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |9...............|
000fb340  3d 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  3f 01 00 00 40 01 00 00  |=.......?...@...|
000fb350  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  43 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........C.......|
000fb360  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 48 01 00 00  |............H...|
000fb370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  4b 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........K.......|
000fb380  4d 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  4f 01 00 00 50 01 00 00  |M.......O...P...|
000fb390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb3a0  55 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  57 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |U.......W.......|
000fb3b0  59 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 5c 01 00 00  |Y...........\...|
000fb3c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 60 01 00 00  |............`...|
000fb3d0  61 01 00 00 62 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |a...b...........|
000fb3e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 68 01 00 00  |............h...|
000fb3f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  6b 01 00 00 6c 01 00 00  |........k...l...|
000fb400  6d 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  6f 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |m.......o.......|
000fb410  71 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |q...............|
000fb420  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 01 00 00 78 01 00 00  |........w...x...|
000fb430  79 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  7b 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |y.......{.......|
000fb440  7d 01 00 00 7e 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |}...~...........|
000fb450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb460  85 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  87 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb470  00 00 00 00 8a 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb480  8d 01 00 00 8e 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb490  91 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  93 01 00 00 94 01 00 00  |................|
000fb4a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 98 01 00 00  |................|
000fb4b0  99 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb4c0  00 00 00 00 9e 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 a0 01 00 00  |................|
000fb4d0  a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb4e0  a5 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb4f0  00 00 00 00 aa 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 ac 01 00 00  |................|
000fb500  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 b0 01 00 00  |................|
000fb510  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 b4 01 00 00  |................|
000fb520  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 b8 01 00 00  |................|
000fb530  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 bc 01 00 00  |................|
000fb540  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  bf 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb550  c1 01 00 00 c2 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 c4 01 00 00  |................|
000fb560  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c7 01 00 00 c8 01 00 00  |................|
000fb570  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  cb 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb580  cd 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb590  d1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb5a0  00 00 00 00 d6 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb5b0  00 00 00 00 da 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 dc 01 00 00  |................|
000fb5c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb5d0  00 00 00 00 e2 01 00 00  e3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb5e0  e5 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000fb5f0  e9 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  eb 01 00 00 ec 01 00 00  |................|
000fb600  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 f0 01 00 00  |................|


Doesn't look like 400 lines is enough to actually get any real radar returns in it.

I can't find much documentation on the format. Can you upload the whole file?

@Chris Give me a few hours and I’ll upload the data to GitHub (or some public means of accessing it)

@Chris https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eefw64genulajjpip80qt/SBA-17JUL24_0200-0500Z.cdr?rlkey=11uukk2lrwduvth79rrytzuu0&st=jo4dnpy0&dl=0 I'll leave this download link up for a few days

@Chris here's a different CDR file that's from the SCT radar https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/y2atodpqihemyz3unt90w/SCT-07-17-24_0200-0500z.cdr.gz?rlkey=ypwovgr2s5t6yvay23815iqvt&st=gbyz3q9x&dl=0 I'll leave this up for a few days

As far as I can tell, the format isn't publicly documented. Inspecting the binary file, the actual radar contacts appear to be ASCII text of fixed length. Example:

17:35:56 07/15/24  TRF1 N593TC    CXP  C208 7271 D SBA*NTH 1E 0MVI003+00029-00036 164 089

These records can be extracted using the Linux grep utility using the following command:
grep -Poa '([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9][0-9].{73}$' input_filename.cdr | awk '!x[$0]++' > output_filename.txt
which extracts lines beginning with a UTC timestamp followed by 73 more characters. Each record appears in the file several hundred times and the awk command extracts only non-duplicates.
As for the actual format of the record, some of it is pretty clear. Some of it not so much. My best guesses so far:



Offset
Length
Field
Example




0
8
UTC Time
17:35:56


9
8
UTC Date
07/15/24


19
4
Unknown. Something like a type of return? CST indicates Coasting (no radar return) status. HND likely indicates handoff status.
TRF1


24
7
* Call sign
N593TC


34
3
* Scratchpad information. Often either destination or assigned runway; sometimes other mnemonic like PIX or JFA. *** indicates no scratchpad data.
CXP


39
4
* Type
C208


44
4
* Squawk code
7271


49
1
Arrival, Departure, or Enroute flight (relative to any airport in the facility's airspace)
D


51
7
Unknown, something about radar facility/data source maybe? Could also be entry/exit fixes.
SBA*NTH


59
2
* Owning TCP (control position, scope)
1E


61
2
Unknown. 1st is always either blank or C. 2nd is always 0.
0


63
1
* Minimum Safe Altitude Warning disabled. Near-certain discriminator between IFR and VFR target, although not 100% guaranteed.
M


64
1
* Special designator symbol. Blank for IFR arrival or departure. E for IFR overflight. V for VFR of any kind.
V


65
1
* Consolidated Wake Turbulence category (A-I).
I


66
3
* Flight level or altitude
003


69
12
Appears to be a position of some kind. Perhaps x and y coordinates?
+00029-00036


82
3
Probably course. It ranges from 0 to 359
164


86
3
* Ground speed
089



*Displayed to ATC on the scope (data block or target symbol)
This obviously isn't complete, but I'm posting it in case anyone else has any insights and so I don't accidentally close the tab and delete my partial answer!

Very nice. Added a couple clarifications. It would be helpful to see more of the grepped data, especially to see multiple different entries for the same track... unfortunately the version of grep I have on my machine doesn't like the command you used. Would you be able to upload your output.txt? Ideally without stripping out duplicates?

@randomhead The multiple different entries are all bitwise identical. They appear anywhere from once to 279 times each. There's a lot of binary data I haven't got around to looking at yet. Including what looks to be at least one embedded executable or library of some sort.

I see. Just scrolling through I can come across the various radar hits here and there and that's enough to add a little more info.

@randomhead Good call on ground speed. And the one before it looks to be the course.

This is not raw radar output but surveillancd data processing system / flight data processing system output. This aggregates data from multiple surveillance sensors and adds flight data such as VFR/IFR info, wake turbulence category etc. The 12 character azimuth/range field are likely X/Y position coordinates.

This is great! I actually another larger CDR from SCT that I haven't analyzed yet. I'm happy to upload and post if anyone wants to take a shot at it to see if the data is the same or different

SCT cdr file here's the link for the SCT CDR file https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/y2atodpqihemyz3unt90w/SCT-07-17-24_0200-0500z.cdr.gz?rlkey=ypwovgr2s5t6yvay23815iqvt&st=gbyz3q9x&dl=0 I'll leave this up for a few days

@likeabbas Data format looks the same. I see 14,186 unique records in the dataset using the same grep command above. (1,541,095 total records, so there's a lot of duplicates in there!)
